# list of definitions in appendix

Tags: glossaries

I want to have appendixes containing an overview of RFC, W3C and other standards discussed in my paper. Of course I also have them in my bibliography, but the overview should look like

```
RFC 1234 Title of the standard
                                                     http://link.to/standard
Short multi line summary what this standard is about and why it is important for my paper.
```

I want the overview to look like a glossary, but I think none of the glosseries packages are quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'd suggest to use [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) for this. Sorry, but I'm out of time, so I cannot make a MWE on my own this afternoon. Maybe someone else will do it.

Comment: @ThomasKoch Please post an example of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've found the answer: [plain simple description lists](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Description). The package expdlist can help with customization.